# CSS / HTML - stray dash appearing on hover

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have a section on a site containing logos for product partners. There's around 28 logos in all - 10 of them are links to separate product pages. When I hover over them there's a stray dash that appears in the bottom right-hand corner and I cannot find where this is coming from and it's sending me crazy. It appears on all the linked logo images except the last one - again I can't see the difference with this one. This is what I mean -

**Logo with dash appearing**

[image: with dash]

**Without dash**

[image: without]

It looks like a stray dash from a page of code but I can't see anything -

**partners.php**

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="partnerimages" class="col-md">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(76); ?>" id="adia">
      <?php if( get_field('axe_img') ): ?>
      <img src="<?php the_field('axe_img'); ?>" />
      <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
    <?php if( get_field('beachrotana_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('beachrotana_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(78); ?>" id="adia">
      <?php if( get_field('bloom_img') ): ?>
      <img src="<?php the_field('bloom_img'); ?>" />
      <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(80); ?>" id="adia">
      <?php if( get_field('bodytree_img') ): ?>
      <img src="<?php the_field('bodytree_img'); ?>" />
      <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(82); ?>" id="adia">
      <?php if( get_field('certo_img') ): ?>
      <img src="<?php the_field('certo_img'); ?>" />
      <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
    <?php if( get_field('daphne_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('daphne_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('ecolab_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('ecolab_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(84); ?>" id="adia">
      <?php if( get_field('fish_img') ): ?>
      <img src="<?php the_field('fish_img'); ?>" />
      <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
    <?php if( get_field('fsw_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('fsw_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('gloss_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('gloss_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(86); ?>" id="adia">
      <?php if( get_field('guy_img') ): ?>
      <img src="<?php the_field('guy_img'); ?>" />
      <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
    <?php if( get_field('happiness_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('happiness_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('herbal_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('herbal_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('ignite_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('ignite_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('js_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('js_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('khalidya_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('khalidya_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(88); ?>" id="adia">
      <?php if( get_field('lucky_img') ): ?>
      <img src="<?php the_field('lucky_img'); ?>" />
      <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(90); ?>" id="adia">
      <?php if( get_field('lux_img') ): ?>
      <img src="<?php the_field('lux_img'); ?>" />
      <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
    <?php if( get_field('madiso_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('madiso_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('maria_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('maria_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('prca_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('prca_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('qcomm_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('qcomm_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('radwater_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('radwater_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('radmedia_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('radmedia_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(92); ?>" id="adia">
      <?php if( get_field('shangri_img') ): ?>
      <img src="<?php the_field('shangri_img'); ?>" />
      <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
    <?php if( get_field('sofrank_img') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('sofrank_img'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(94); ?>" id="adia">
      <?php if( get_field('tips_img') ): ?>
      <img src="<?php the_field('tips_img'); ?>" />
      <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(96); ?>" id="adia">
      <?php if( get_field('xbd_img') ): ?>
      <img src="<?php the_field('xbd_img'); ?>" />
      <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If it's not from the text editor where else could it be? I've checked the pages and the ACF's. Can anyone assist / see anything I can't?

Comment: That'll be whitespace inside the `<a>`.  Throwing a ` text-decoration:none` on that link would be the simplest fix.

Comment: You are also using duplicate `ID`s which is [not valid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993450/w3c-errors-for-duplicate-ids).

Comment: This is a HTML/CSS question. Please remove all the PHP from your example. Some of us don't run PHP and can't/won't help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the HTML is invalid by using multiple id attributes on the elements.

Comment: @Rob The `id` issue doesn't make this a question that should be closed. The question is about an unrelated issue.

Comment: @Rob I'm a 40-something self-learner sat in the corner of my kitchen. I use this platform to find answers but also to learn - the ID thing is a simple error on my part which I'll learn from next time. If you just close questions down, people like me can't really learn from people like you. Hope that's okay:)

Comment: When one asks a question about a program written in C, and the compiler emits an error saying the code is invalid, that question will be closed for the same reason. An error is an error and anything else is a hack to fit a square peg in a round hole. Fix your code first.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead Rob is wrong on this. Don't worry about him. He points out a valid issue with your code, but it is unrelated to your question and wouldn't stop your code from running like in his C example, which is apples to watermelons.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Until he has a problem and then he'll come back wondering why it doesn't work anymore. Don't say I'm wrong while saying I have a valid point.

Comment: @Rob The `id` issue will not ever cause the problem being asked about here and the solution to not work. It is a completely separate issue. Your pointing it out is valid, you are wrong to vote to close the question because of it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus To ignore his invalid HTML would be irresponsible. You would be sending him off, only to struggle later and not understand why, and then have to backtrack all over again.

Comment: @Rob That’s why you were right to point it out in a comment. It addresses your concerns. Voting to close was not right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTML, white space is "normalized". This means that multiple white space characters in a row will be compacted down to a single white space character. But, it also means that other non-printable characters are converted to space characters, including carriage returns.

So, if you write a hyperlink like this:

```
<a href="somePath">Some content</a>
```

There only content of the `a` element is the text and all of that text is what will be clickable and, if underlining is applied, all the text will be underlined.

But, in your case your code basically works out to be like this:

```
<a href="somePath">
  <img src="somePath"></a>
```

Which puts a carriage return inside the opening and closing `a` element and that carriage return gets converted to a space and that space is now part of the content of the element. If underlining gets applied, that space will get underlined.

So, you can just re-work your HTML structure to not include carriage returns in your code or you can turn off underlining for links with the following CSS:

```
a  { text-decoration:none; }
```

Comment: It's still there, it must be something so small I'm missing it. The one thing I've found, though, is that the reason it doesn't happen on the XBD logo is because it's at the end of the row. When I re-size the page and the other logos cascade - when they're at the end of the row the dash doesn't show.

Comment: Never use CSS selectors without any specificity. ;-)

Comment: @JoostS Says who? That's  exactly what you'd do if you want to affect all matching elements within a document.

Comment: I want to save you from the monster that is called 'ever growing css'. You have probably met him a few times... ;-)

Comment: @JoostS You are generalizing. Very specific selectors improve performance, but create a brittle stylesheet. No wonder you find yourself using `!important`. There is nothing wrong with general selectors when making general style declarations. They leave room for overriding with a more specific one later and don't cause you to style yourself into a corner. And, "ever growing CSS" would more likely be caused by specific selectors being used right out of the gate. By its very nature a general selector will lead to less CSS, not more.

Comment: Carriage returns?! Browsers ignore carriage returns. Tabs, too! This is white space we are talking about.

Comment: @Rob Wrong my friend. Non-printable characters get converted to spaces and multiple consecutive spaces get compressed to a single space.

Comment: Can't find the current standard. [Here is HTML 4.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/struct/text.html) concerning text: " for all elements except PRE, leading white space characters, such as spaces, horizontal tabs, form feeds and line breaks, following the start tag must be ignored, and any subsequent sequence of contiguous white space characters must be replaced by a single word space."

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sorted it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have a feeling we aren't talking about the same thing. I was talking about carriage returns within the text. You are talking about carriage returns within the markup. Carriage returns within the markup result in one space.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Very specific selectors might improve performance, but they mostly create a rock solid (but lengthy) stylesheet that is easy to manipulate. A general selector on the other hand can never be touched without (re)testing all pages and should therefore be used as little as possible. The hierarchical structure of SASS and LESS seem to follow this logic, by making it easy to be super [specific](https://specifishity.com/specifishity.pdf). However, please use CSS the way you like it. My comment was mostly referring to your comment (hence the wink). Live and let live. Agree to disagree.

Comment: @ScottMarcus PS. I never style myself in a corner... I use inline `!important` to prevent that... ;-)... No? Still not funny? Sorry man!

Comment: @ScottMarcus PPS. I think @Mike.Whitehead fixed it in the meantime with `!important`. ;-)))) Enough with the jokes. Know that I gave your answer an upvote. You deserve it (for real). Good answer, clear explanation. Have a nice evening!

Comment: @Rob Same thing. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/pkL0knuv/5/ All the markup in the text of the `a` includes carriage returns as part of the text.

Comment: I didn’t use !important. Sorry. I’d be a liar though if I said I’d never used it before:)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pkL0knuv/6/ :-)))) I used `!important` inline to be extra gross. ;-) Do not try this at home kids!

Comment: It is not the same thing. Put three carriage returns in a row between those images and you'll see only one space. That is what I was talking about.

Comment: @Rob I know. I told you non-printable chars. get converted to spaces and multiple spaces get compacted to a single space. I’ve said that at least three times.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Are you allowed to put classes in an <a> tag? I've tried changing id="adia" to class="adia" and the img:hover {background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);} rule won't work.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead You can, but your CSS rule needs to change to be:  .ada:hover

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem for sure:

```
#partnerimages a:hover {text-decoration:none!important;}
```

You are seeing an underline, not a dash.

Comment: `!important` is only recommended as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks Scott, you are right. However, here it is used after an id selector that holds clearly only links and images (we can see that in the code and in the name of the id). Also, we do not know what the CSS of Mike looks like. I used it on purpose for convenience and speed of fixing/resolving this issue.

Comment: *" I used it on purpose for convenience and speed of fixing/resolving this issue."* Which is exactly when not to use it.